# c# program : Getting error with SQLTransaction commands with lot of INSERT statements

Tags: c#, pipe, commit, bulkinsert, sqltransaction

Update 1: The below code works fine on my DEV machine but fails on TEST/Production server.

```
public TransImport()
{
ConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection conn_new;
SqlCommand command_serial_new;
SqlTransaction InsertUpdateSerialNumbers;

conn_new = new SqlConnection(ConnString);
command_serial_new = conn_new.CreateCommand();
command_serial_new.CommandText = "SELECT 1 FROM YSL00020 WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE SERLNMBR = @slnr";
var p = new SqlParameter("@slnr", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
command_serial_new.Parameters.Add(p);

InsertUpdateSerialNumbers = conn.BeginTransaction();
boolean bErrors = false;
while (!headerFileReader.EndOfStream)
{
     headerRow = headerFileReader.ReadLine();

     if (!CheckSerialNumber(headerFields[0].Trim()))
        {
        bErrors = true;
        break;
        }
  }
if (bErrors)
  InsertUpdateSerialNumbers.Commit();
else
  InsertUpdateSerialNumbers.Rollback();

if (conn_new != null)
{
    conn_new.Close();
    conn_new.Dispose();
}
```

}

```
private Boolean CheckSerialNumber(string SerialNumber)
{
command_serial_new.Parameters["@slnr"].Value = SerialNumber;
try
{
    var itExists = Convert.ToInt32(command_serial_new.ExecuteScalar()) > 0;
    if (!itExists)
    {
        command_serial.Transaction = InsertUpdateSerialNumbers;
        command_serial.CommandText = "INSERT INTO YSL00([Manifest_Number],[PONUMBER],[ITEMNMBR],[SERLNMBR]"
         + "VALUES ('" + Manifest + "','" + PONr + "','" + itemNumber + "','" + serialNr  + "')";
        var insertStatus = command_serial.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return true;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    LogException(ex, "Error in CheckSerialNumber =>"+ command_serial_new.CommandText.ToString());
}
return false;
}
```

Issues I am facing with above code:

I am using SQLTransaction with commit & rollback. I loop through a flat file and update some tables. File contains usually around 500 to 1000 lines. I am creating INSERT statement for every row (with sqltransaction) and the program halts for a long time at COMMIT statement and ultimately I get errors as shown below. However if I am comment out the entire sqltransaction (and commit plus rollback), everything is fine, but we need commit & rollback. Is there a way to create just one transaction (I am right now creating for every INSERT statement) such that I don't get errors like below.

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException
```

There was an error reading from the pipe: The pipe has been ended. (109, 0x6d).
mscorlib

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.Receive(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SynchronizedMessageSource.Receive(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.Receive(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.FramingDuplexSessionChannel.TryReceive(TimeSpan timeout, Message& message)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DuplexChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements (like your `INSERT`) - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things that will help improve this.

First wrap `SqlConnection` command in `using`.

Second sounds like prod is taking longer to run this and that's why it's timing out. You can set timeout to unlimited.

Last if you are using SQL Server 2008+ you should use batch inserts.

```
Insert into table (column1, column2) values (value1, value2), (value3, value4)
```

Another side note when dynamically building these there is a limit of a thousand values being in steered at once.

Comment: I have tried the sqlconnection command with USING but no help so far. How do I do batch inserts? That may work for me as it will be just one transaction for SQLTransaction, but then I have to consider the length of the query?

Answer (score 0):

Modified my code with batch inserts and there were no issues.